# MySQL : INSERT INTO with foreach like

Tags: mysql, select, foreach, insert

i want to do a query like this :

```
INSERT INTO `gesdoc_docs_authorizations`
    (`gesdoc_docs_id`, `id_profil_do`, `autorisation`, `personal_doc`)
VALUES (
    (SELECT `id`
    FROM `gesdoc_docs`),
    (SELECT `id`
    FROM `users_profil_do`),
    1, 0
   );
```

Table `gesdoc_docs` has 40 rows and `users_profil_do` has 700 rows.
I need to have for each row in `users_profil_do` the 40 rows of `andco_gesdoc_docs` associated (so normally my query will insert 28,000 rows).
Is it possible ? How can i do that with a mysql query ?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use the `VALUES` keyword when inserting from a `SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO gesdoc_docs_authorizations
    (`gesdoc_docs_id`, `id_profil_do`, `autorisation`, `personal_doc`)
SELECT g.id, d.id, 1, 0
FROM gesdoc_docs g
JOIN users_profil_do d
```

If you don't use an `ON` clause to specify a join condition, it treats all rows as matching, which results in a full cartesian product of the two tables.

Comment: Thanks it works :) I don't knowed that you can use JOIN without joins on column, good to learn this !

Comment: @TikTaZ [INNER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join) without join column will perform a Cartesian product. Say table t1 has (1),(2) and table t2 has (3),(4), then `t1 JOIN t2` will produce *4* combinations: (1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4).